# logging error : TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python-3.7, django-2.2

when I updated the python from 2.7.16 to 3.7.4 on my project,the django console show logging error as follows:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python37\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1028, in emit
    stream.write(msg + self.terminator)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

But It works fine when i used python2.7

My Env:windows 10 python3.7.4 django2.2.5 eclipse+pydev7.3.0.201908161924
the django settings.py about the logging part

```
log_path = config.get('log', 'log_path')  #windows path

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s|%(levelname)s|%(process)d|%(funcName)s|%(lineno)d|msg:%(message)s'
        },
        'verbose': {
            'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {module} {process:d} {thread:d} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '{levelname} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],  #  DEBUG = False sendemail
            'include_html':True,
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
        'default': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(log_path,'skstack.log'),  
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 5,  
            'backupCount': 5,  
            'formatter': 'verbose',  
        },
        'error_file': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(log_path,'skstack-error.log'),
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'info_file': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(log_path,'skstack-info.log'),
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'debug': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(log_path,'skstack-debug.log'),
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 5,  
            'backupCount': 5,  
            'formatter': 'verbose',  
        },

        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
         'skworkorders_log': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(log_path,'skworkorders.log'),
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },

    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'info_file'],
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'info_file'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'skstack': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'info_file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
         'skworkorders': {
            'handlers': ['skworkorders_log','console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}
```

the full error log

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python37\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1028, in emit
    stream.write(msg + self.terminator)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
Call stack:
  File "c:\python37\Lib\threading.py", line 890, in _bootstrap
    self._bootstrap_inner()
  File "c:\python37\Lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\python37\Lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\python37\Lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "c:\python37\Lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "c:\python37\Lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\virtualEnv\sk-stack\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\virtualEnv\sk-stack\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "c:\python37\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "c:\python37\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 196, in finish_response
    self.close()
  File "C:\virtualEnv\sk-stack\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "c:\python37\Lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
  File "c:\python37\Lib\http\server.py", line 544, in log_request
    self.requestline, str(code), str(size))
  File "C:\virtualEnv\sk-stack\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 154, in log_message
    level(format, *args, extra=extra)
Message: '"%s" %s %s'
Arguments: ('GET /skworkorders/WorkOrderCommit/ HTTP/1.1', '200', '35764')
```

I can see that the django request log has been recorded in skstack-info.log

```
2019-09-19 11:44:40,515|INFO|60880|log_message|154|msg:"GET 
/skworkorders/WorkOrderCommit/ HTTP/1.1" 200 35764
```

when i modify File "c:\python37\Lib\logging__init__.py", line 1029, in emit

```
stream.write(msg + self.terminator)
```

to

```
stream.write(str.encode(msg + self.terminator))
```

it also show me the another error as following:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python37\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1029, in emit
    stream.write(str.encode(msg + self.terminator))
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Comment: I tried the following, but it didn't work:
1 reinstall the python virtual machine environment;
2 use django 1.11.x version;

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem，use the  following methods

1.I search my code use “logging” as a key word and find i have setup the logging.basicConfig in another palce
 2.I change the file mode  from filemode='ab+' to filemode='a+' then It worked fine
 3.The complete settings are as follows

```
  logging.basicConfig(level=dic[level],
                format='%(asctime)s|%(levelname)s|%(pathname)s|%(funcName)s|%(lineno)d|[msg:%(message)s]',
                datefmt='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S',
                filename=log_path+log_name,
                filemode='a+')
```

Answer (score 0):

when I unable  logging.loggers.django like the following , It worked fine,but I can't see the django logs anymore on the IDE consle

```
    'loggers': {
#         'django': {
#             'handlers': ['console'],
#             'propagate': True,
#         },
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the error, exactly as you mentioned it is enough to use the

```
filemode='a+'
```

I was using bw and after changing to a+, it immediately started to work on Python3.7.

Hope that can help a bit more.
Thanks and regards,
Marco